# Как в GORM использовать тип данных jsonb из PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, golang

Я решил хранить информацию в поле типа `jsonb` в PostgreSQL.

Нужно записывать значения и производить выборку. Или вставлять просто SQL код?

Answer (score -2):

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/ - внимательное изучение поможет отцу русской демократии.

Дампить данные в базу лучше в байтовом виде, используя **Marshal**,**Unmarshal**. Все прозаично на самом деле.